# Get the automatic excerpt from a page created with gutenberg

Tags: excerpt

The problem I have is im not getting the automatic excerpt (the_excerpt()) when I create a post with gutenberg blocks, If I put an image or something before the text it looks like gutenberg does not undestand it, if I put just text is ok but If I add images or a different block that is not text it is empty, is there a way to detect the first block of text in a post and use it like excerpt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook the `get_the_excerpt` filter with `parse_blocks` to extract the content of your post.

```php
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'se378694_default_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function se378694_default_excerpt( string $post_excerpt, WP_Post $post ):string {
    if ( empty( $post_excerpt ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );

        // check if the first block matches the type of content you want for your excerpt
        if ( ... ) {
            $post_excerpt = render_block( $blocks[ 0 ] );
        }
    }
}
```

You can use [render_block()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/render_block/) if you want to get the final content of any block in your post content.

And [parse_blocks()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/) to convert the post content (string) into an array of blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer Tim but Im a little bit confused what can I put in the if statement to display text? them I have to call get_the_excerpt(); where I want to display the excerpt? Thank you

Comment: get_the_ecxerpt() or the_excerpt() are the standard methods to get or print the excerpt in your template.

Comment: The code provided will add a hook everytime someone try to get or print the excerpt. You can try to var_dump the $blocks variable to see what is inside. There is a property that will tell you the block name (core/paragraph) for example. Of it is a paragraph, then try to render it and return the value to generate your excerpt.